# External DVD-ROM drive can't read discs on my PC but can on another PC

Tags: dvd

I'm newbie with computers and have little few experience with hardware. Yesterday, I bought an external DVD-ROM drive (Samsung, USB Slim Portable Optical Drive).

However the drive can't read any CDs or DVDs on my PC. If I try on another PC it works fine.

What's wrong with my PC? I'm using Windows XP SP2.

---

I'm sorry for my bad English. English is not my primary language. :-)

**@harper89:**
Yes, PC2 was connect to the internet, but my computer didn't. I try to re-install my OS and update my motherboard drivers and my PC is fine. I also read my DVD Rom manual book, and it tell that the drive would install the driver automatically. But, the problem is same, my computer still can't read the disc. What kind of "device" do you mean in device manager?

**@wizlog:**
What kind of drivers I should install on my PC? I think my DVD Rom has been install the drivers on my PC automatically as it said in the manual book. And when I click my computer, it show a new driver (something like this E:/DVD-ROM).

Comment: Did PC 2 connect to the internet and download a driver? Does PC1 show the device in device manager? Could you explain a bit more? it will help get a better answer.

Comment: update drivers...